# Can browser extensions keylog user input?

Tags: javascript, html, security, encryption, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on an app that encrypts and stores sensitive user data in `localStorage`. Passwords for encryption/decryption not saved anywhere. So, if a user loses his password, there's no way to decrypt the data.
From what I know browser extensions have access to `localStorage` on any page and can listen to events from any element on the page (`input` for example). This is the problem, because a malicious extension can keylog user password, get encrypted data from `localStorage` and decrypt it using the password.

My questions are:

1. Is there a way to disable extensions from a webpage?
2. Is there a way to prevent extension from gaining access to the `localStorage` on a page?
3. Is there another more secure approach to what I want to do?

Comment: Web pages and client-side web apps are defenseless, but you can write an extension yourself and do all the sensitive stuff inside.

Comment: In the end you may not want to take full responsibility of which extensions *the user decides to download and run*. You can always *recommend* to not install extensions, to disable extensions when running your app or indeed to use a separate installation without extensions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. No.
2. Not if the user allowed the extension access.
3. Probably, see below.

I think there are multiple problems with this approach.

As @wOxxOm noted, client-side things are totally under control of the browser (in this case), and browser settings are governed by your enduser (or policies applied to the client computer). One thing you could think of doing is having your app run in private / incognito mode, because that disables extensions by default, but even then the user can allow extensions for incognito mode, and it wouldn't help much anyway for reasons described below (and besides that, you can't reliably detect if the user is using private / incognito mode, so it would have to be a mere recommendation anyway).

My second point is also already commented by @MaartenBodewes. Choosing extensions (and granting them privileges) is the responsibiliy of your user. If he trusts an extension so much that he adds it to his browser, it's ultimately his risk. You can warn about this, but the decision always should sit with the user.

And my most important point is, this wouldn't help anyway. As [some](https://www.nccgroup.trust/us/about-us/newsroom-and-events/blog/2011/august/javascript-cryptography-considered-harmful/) [people](https://tonyarcieri.com/whats-wrong-with-webcrypto) already noted, cryptography in Javascript used to be hopeless. If you target older browsers, this is really a bad idea. New browsers brought major improvements (see the accepted answer [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/133277/problems-with-in-browser-crypto/133288)), Content-Security-Policy and the new crypto API are good (albeit not very well supported across browsers and versions).

But still, there can always be flaws in your app that negate all security efforts. A single instance of cross-site scripting will leave you unprotected against such threats. If you are so concerned about security that you want your users to not use extensions that they thought were ok, you should be similarly concerned about risks like this too.

So in short, I think if a malicious browser extension is a major threat in your threat model, the web is probably not a good platform for your application unfortunately. On the other hand, writing something like a native application has its own threats, very different from a web app, so the decision is yours. No matter what you do, there will always be residual risk that you will have to accept or transfer in some way.